# Python Changing the value accross a Data Frame column

Tags: python

I'm trying to change a Data Frame column value to some number I generate, by using a while loop that goes over the column
The number (called "num") is calculated ok.
I think the problem is with the line in the end of the while loop:

```
data.ix[i]['numOfDocuments'] = num
```

Even when trying

```
data.ix[i]['numOfDocuments'] = 2
```

the values stays 0 (I used print data[numOfDocuments].sum() )

Here is the code:

```
data['numOfDocuments'] = 0
i = 0
while (i < len(data)):
    old_str = data.ix[i]['Params']
    if (old_str != '{}') and (old_str.find('numOfDocuments') != -1):
        str = old_str.replace('{', '').replace('}', '')
        if (str.find(';',str.find('numOfDocuments')) == -1):
            num = int(str[(str.find('numOfDocuments') + 17)::])
        else:
            num = int(str[(str.find('numOfDocuments') + 17):(str.find(';',str.find('numOfDocuments')))])
    else:
        num = None
    data.ix[i]['numOfDocuments'] = num
    i += 1
```

Comment: solved it, by using: data.at[i,'numOfDocuments'] = num

Comment: you can post your solution as an answer...